# How to access OnPress event that happens outside the component?

Tags: react-native

I am creating a custom dropdown component in React Native. I want to close it contents, when user presses screen outside of the component on any other part of the application.

However, I cannot know if user pressed outside the component. Is there a global OnPress event that can accessed or some other way, kindly let me know.

Comment: Please provide what have you treid so far

Comment: I was looking at this, but I am not sure if it even works in React native because in web you can access global events, not sure about React native.
https://medium.com/@pitipatdop/little-neat-trick-to-capture-click-outside-react-component-5604830beb7f

Comment: Take a look [here](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/overlay.html)

Comment: I need to programatically know if user pressed outside the element. Is it possible or not and how it should be done if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:

add a logic when you click dropdown it should create a transparent view covering wholescreen in a absolute position.

Do it Like this:
// inside render

```
<Fragment>
         <Nested>
           <DropDown/>
         </Nested>

           {isDrop &&
            <View style={styles.container} // height:'100%', width:'100%', backgroundColor:transparent , position: 'absolute'
              //Trigger for pressing outside DropDown
               onResponderStart={() => { condition for dropdown}} 
              //Required to start interacting with touches
               onStartShouldSetResponder={(e) => {return true}}/>}

</Fragment>
```

DropDown component and view with touch must be the same level

Comment: There are nesting within components, Also event can occur on any part of the screen, So I don't think its practical to pass events down the children components for this particular usecase.

Comment: you are right. TouchableWithoutFeedback component will be required to fill the whole screen and it will be positioned absolute. I will write some clean code for it and also upload it as a solution or you should clean up your answer a little so I wont have to do an effort for other viewers:)